# SSH from windows to AIX

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, ssh-keys, aix

I am trying to do SSH from Windows to AIX.

I am able to do SSH.But i have some doubt how SSH is working here.

pqp1111 is the user in AIX server.

In home directory of pqp1111 i can see below key is placed

```
     /home/pqp1111/.ssh/authorized_keys
     ssh - rsa ......................@hostnameofwindows
```

My understanding was we need private key of target server to SSH.But in this case below is the way i am doing SSH and its working.

```
 "ssh pqp1111@AIXservername ls -a"
```

I am not getting how this SSH is working without private key ?

Answer (score 2):

On the target host (AIX) you need only your public key, your private key should be only located on your local machine.
So everything looks fine
AIX includes your public key in authorized keys file.
Your windows machine has got its own private key which decrypt initial traffic from AIX which was encrypted by your public key.

You should never share your private key, only public key!

Comment: But i dont have to pass private key while making SSH?

Comment: In most cases you don't have to pass private key while making SSH, you ssh client will find your private key to decrypt traffic itself.

`
ls -la ~/.ssh/
`
and there you will see your private and public keys